# Loading PNG as String and saving corrupts it

Tags: java, load, png

I have program in which I have to load a PNG as a String and then save it again, but after I save it it becomes unreadable. If I open both the loaded PNG and the saved String in the editor, I can see that java created linebreaks all over the file. If this is is the problem, how can I avoid this?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            File file1 = new File("C://andim//testFile.png");
            StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
            String s = null;         
            while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                content.append(s).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));                      
            }
            reader.close();
            String loaded=content.toString();
            File file2=new File("C://andim//testString.png");
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file2);
            filewriter.write(loaded);           
            filewriter.flush();
            filewriter.close();
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: *"I have program in which I have to load a PNG as a String and then save it again.."* That is ridiculous.

Comment: Why are you loading/saving a PNG (image ?) as String (text) in the first place?

Comment: [Google-searching "png to string"](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=png+to+string&oq=png+to+string) got me an awful lot of results that would have led this question never being asked. --- I'll assume there was no research-effort at all here. (-1)

Comment: BTW, why the double slashes in the path name? They work but they don't make sense. Either use escaped backslashes \\ or single slashes /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have program in which I have to load a PNG as a String and then save it again, but after I save it it becomes unreadable.

Yes, I'm not surprised. You're treating arbitrary binary data as if it's text data (in whatever your platform default encoding is, to boot). It's not. Don't do that. It's possible that in some encodings you'll get away with it - until you start trying to pass the string elsewhere in a way that strips unprintable characters etc.

If you *must* convert arbitrary binary data to text, use base64 or hex. If possible, avoid the conversion to text in the first place though. If you just want to copy a file, use `InputStream` and `OutputStream` - *not* `Reader` and `Writer`.

This is a big general point: keep data in its "native" representation as long as you possibly can. Only convert data to a different representation when you absolutely have to, and be very careful about it.

Comment: The reason why i'm doing it is that i have to pack a String and an PNG in the same File. How i can do it?

Comment: @D180: Either separate them within the file, so you know which bit of the file to treat as binary data and which to treat as text, or use base64 to encode the binary data (as per my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use text-based APIs to read binary files. In this case, you don't want a `BufferedReader`, and you certainly don't want `readLine`, which may well treat more than just one thing as a line separator. Use an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) (for instance, [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)) and an [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) (for instance, [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)), not readers and writers.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't do that

PNGs are not textual data.
If you try to read arbitrary bytes into a string, Java will mangle the bytes into actual text, corrupting the data you read.

You need to use `byte[]`sm not `string`s.